# Using AppleScript to import emails from Canary Mail to DEVONthink 3

Tags: applescript, email, automator

I'm trying to use AppleScript to import emails from Canary Mail into DEVONthink 3 on my Mac.

When I run the script below I get the error message:

> Expected “,” but found identifier.

I have also tried running it as a Quick Action in Automator, but this produces a -212 error.

What do I need to change in the script?

```
tell application "Canary Mail"
    activate
    set selectedMessages to selection
    if selectedMessages is {} then
        display alert "No messages selected" message "Please select one or more messages to import into DEVONthink 3."
    else
        set messageCount to count of selectedMessages
        set messageIndex to 1
        repeat with theMessage in selectedMessages
            set theSubject to subject of theMessage
            set theDate to date received of theMessage
            set theSender to sender of theMessage
            set theBody to content of theMessage
            set theAttachmentCount to count of attachments of theMessage
            set theAttachments to {}
            if theAttachmentCount > 0 then
                repeat with theAttachment in attachments of theMessage
                    set theAttachmentPath to (path to temporary items folder as string) & name of theAttachment
                    save theAttachment in theAttachmentPath
                    set the end of theAttachments to theAttachmentPath
                end repeat
            end if
            tell application "DEVONthink 3"
                set theGroup to create record with {name:theSubject & ".eml", type:unknown, creation date:theDate, URL:theSender} in root of current database
                set plain text of theGroup to theBody
                if theAttachmentCount > 0 then
                    repeat with theAttachmentPath in theAttachments
                        create record with {name:(last item of (path components of theAttachmentPath)), type:file, URL:theAttachmentPath} in theGroup
                    end repeat
                end if
            end tell
            set messageIndex to messageIndex + 1
        end repeat
        display notification messageCount & " messages imported into DEVONthink 3." with title "Canary Mail"
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from `set the end of theAttachments to theAttachmentPath`. Try removing `the` before `end` to make it `set end of theAttachments to theAttachmentPath`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this hasn't corrected the problem.

Comment: Also, this will probably not work but try replacing the "&" signs with commas ",".

Comment: Please edit your question to specify which line produced the error. I don't have DT3 but in earlier versions there was no `path component` so try deleting 'component' and maybe it will compile.

Comment: Thanks. Deleting 'component' has allowed it to run (I didn't know which line produced the error, but presumably it was this one). But I'm now getting the following error message: error "Canary Mail got an error: Can’t get selection." number -1728 from selection.